# nginx - temp file: Where is it located?

Tags: nginx

I have installed on my Ubuntu 13.04 nginx (1.2.6) from the package-source. Since this is precompiled I have no real clue where the temp-dir is located. So, my question is basically where to find it? Or to be more precise: How do I retrieve the information from nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what temp dir you mean exactly, but all nginx config are inside `/etc/nginx` and all virtual hosts are defined inside `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and to enable any virtual host it's symlinked inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

I think you can find the info you want if you look inside there.

Comment: Thx, that gave me some kind of direction.